# Subgroups of small groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, online-resources

Is there a book/website where I can find the subgroups of small groups (maybe up to order 20)? I'm working on finding the subgroups of some finite groups for Galois theory exercises and would like to check whether I found all of them. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Cf. [this](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tim Dokchitser's website [GroupNames](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/index.html) has amazing amounts of information about groups of order up to 500 (except those of order 256 or 384), including diagrams of subgroup structure where you can hover your cursor to get basic information about each subgroup.